# Get font resource from TypedArray before API 26

Tags: android

Android O introduced fonts in xml back to API 16 via the support library.  However I am unable to find the support equivalent of `TypedArray.getFont()`, which required API level 26.

```
val array = context.obtainStyledAttributes(styleResId, R.styleable.TextAppearance)
val font = array.getFont(R.styleable.TextAppearance_android_fontFamily) // nope
```

Is there some kind of compat utility class I can use to retrieve a font from a style resource id?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Found a workaround which is to find the resource ID of the font from the `TypedArray`, and then use `ResourcesCompat` to load the font.

```
val array = context.obtainStyledAttributes(styleResId, R.styleable.TextAppearance)
if (array.hasValue(R.styleable.TextAppearance_android_fontFamily)) {
    val fontId = array.getResourceId(R.styleable.TextAppearance_android_fontFamily, -1)
    val typeface = ResourcesCompat.getFont(context, fontId)
}
```

Comment: Typeface font = ResourcesCompat.getFont(context, fontId);

Comment: It's ok. Just could be shorten to one line. Thank you for your post!

Comment: Oh, no - half of the solution is getting the fontId from the TypedArray in the first place

Comment: I see the following warning when implementing this solution: "The resource `@styleable/TextAppearance_android_fontFamily` is marked as private in com.android.support.design. Private resources should not be referenced; they may not be present everywhere, and even where they are they may disappear without notice. To fix this, copy the resource into your own project instead.